# Scraping data only after beginning of a certain text

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

So I have this excerpt from a local website and I want to extract "Name of people" under a separate heading name,then all the "offices" names under a heading offices.
The thing is that I dont know how to get this level of structured info from this page.
WHat all I could do was this , which just prints all the `<ul><li>` and not the specific ones that I want (i.e. only Name & Offices).

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen('http://localhost/xyz.html'))
for x in soup.findAll('ul'):
    print x.li.b
```

This is an excerpt from the webpage. As you can see theses lot of content before and after this headline -"People and Offices". I dont want to print anything from those , im concerned about this section only:-

```
    <h3>...</h3>
    <p>....</p>
    <p>....</p>

    <h2>
       <span class="mw-headline" id="People and Offices">People and Offices</span>
       </h2>
    <p>..</p>
    <p>..</p>
    <ul>..</ul>
    <h3>
       <span class="mw-headline" id="Name">Name</span>
       </h3>
    <ul>
       <li>
           <b>Justin</b>
           "Description about justin........
       </li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
       <li>
           <b>Steve</b>
           "Description about steve........
       </li>
    </ul>

    <h3>
       <span class="mw-headline" id="Offices">Offices</span>
       </h3>
    <ul>
       <li>
           <b>Google HQ</b>
           "Address of google........
       </li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
       <li>
           <b>Microsoft HQ</b>
           "Address of microsoft........
       </li>
    </ul>
```

**I just want to go to the section "People and offices" then print the "Names" and "Offices". While my code above just prints everything inclusive &exclusive of "People and Offices"**. Expected output:-:-

```
Name,
Justin,
Steve,
```

======

```
Offices,
Google HQ,
Microsoft HQ,
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your HTML structure is very linear. There is no boundary between the "Name" and "Office". If you don't have control over this html file structure then you have to get the element by id from `id="Name"` and search forward one-by-one till you hit "Office", this will give all names. Similarly start from `id="Office"` till the end to get all the offices.

You can get the element by

```
soup.find(id="Name")
```

If you have control over the structure of the html, then make sure that names and Offices goes under one group (`div` or `span`) so you can easily scrap it up.

UPDATE:

Hope this solution will help your needs. Change the codes to suit your requirements !

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2


def scrap(url):

    soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen(url))

    break_tags = ['h2', 'h3']

    h2s = soup.findAll("h2")

    do_tag = None

    for tag in h2s:
        if tag.find(id="Do"):
            do_tag = tag
            break

    next_tag = do_tag.findNextSibling()
    while 1:
        if next_tag.name in ['div', 'p']:
            next_tag = next_tag.findNextSibling()
            continue
        if next_tag.name in break_tags:
            break

        #if next_tag.name in ['ul']:
        #    print next_tag.name

        #
        # The structure of the HTML is very bad.. no consistency !
        if next_tag.find("span"):
            print next_tag.find("span").span.text
        else:
            print next_tag.li.b.text

        next_tag = next_tag.findNextSibling()
```

Comment: Hi Haridas,Ill give you an idea consider this page : http://wikitravel.org/en/Johannesburg#Do. How can I get the names of all the places in this section #Do (i.e. Township Tour,Walter Sisulu Botanical Gardens, Constitution Hill...etc) Hope you got the idea. My problem is similar.Thanks

Comment: @shalini I updated my answer with code sample which extract the names from the URL that you given here - http://wikitravel.org/en/Johannesburg#Do - Hope that will help you.

Comment: Hi @haridas-n, I tried your code, but its getting difficult to move ahead for me as Im not able to get desired output & cant paste the local-webpage here too. Can you please tell me on that wikitravel page, how to do it. That will immensely help becasue I cant paste my local-server website info here.

Comment: @shalini Call the `scrap` function with url as -  http://wikitravel.org/en/Johannesburg#Do. I tested with the url that you given. It works for it. But you need to slightly make changes of `break` and `continue` to work with the html code that you pasted with your question.

Answer (score 0):

The `string` function can be used to extract the content within a given tag. For example, to get the content of `<b>`, then

```
print x.li.b.string
```

So the code can be modified as

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen('http://localhost/xyz.html'))

text=soup.find(text='Name').

for x in text.findAllNext('ul'):
    print x.li.b.string,","

text=soup.find(text='Offices').

for x in text.findAllNext('ul'):
    print x.li.b.string,","
```

The `soup.find(text='Name').` will return the tag that matches the text `Name`

Now `text.findAllNext('ul'):` will find all the `ul` that occure after the given text.

same for `Offices`

Comment: But that prints all the of them. I just want all the "Names" after the heading "people and offices". Nothing before or after that. Hows this selective printing possible?

Comment: you are saying that your file contains other `<ul>` tags other than the ones shown in the example?

Comment: Thanks @nu11p01n73R but its printing all the "Names" as well as" Offices". I want to print only the "Names" and then in next iteration "Offices" and so on. Your codes printing them all. Pls help

Answer (score 0):

```
id="([^"]*)"(?:(?!<span[^>]*>).)*?<b>(.*?)<\/b>(?:(?!<span[^>]*>).)*?<b>(.*?)<\/b>
```

Though you should not parse html with regex you can use this as a hack or quickfix.

Use this 
`import re`

`print re.findall(r'id="([^"]*)"(?:(?!<span[^>]*>).)*?<b>(.*?)<\/b>(?:(?!<span[^>]*>).)*?<b>(.*?)<\/b>',str,re.DOTALL)`.

`str` is your html exceerpt.

See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/vR4fY4/4

Comment: vks thanks but I dont want to print all the <li> on the page, I want to go till "People and Offices", and then print the "Names","Offices", then stop. I want this kind of selective printing/scraping. Thanks and I didnt downvote you :-)

Comment: I like your solution.. nerdy :)

Comment: @shalini it prints just what you want.It doesn not print anything else.

Answer (score 0):

From your given html, I think you can approach like this,

```
for h3 in soup.find_all('h3'):
    print h3.text.strip()
    next_tag = h3.findNextSibling()
    while next_tag.name == 'ul':
        print next_tag.li.b.text
        next_tag = next_tag.findNextSibling()
        if not next_tag:
            break
    print '====='
```

It's generic type. You might need to modify it according to your html.